# How to hover multiple elements with only one fixed link

Tags: html, css, hover

I've create a link on number 1, which has it's own width and height, so it covers all A,B,D,E letters (all li's are linkable).

Sample image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/TL9oB.jpg

What i cannot do is to put a background hover effect on A,B,D,E letters, because the link on number 1 covers with it's height and width all of them.

Is there a way i can achieve this? I must stay limited to use only one link.

Thanks a lot in advance.

My code is:

HTML:

```
<span class="one"><a href="#">1</a></span> <span class="two">2</span>
<ul>
<li>
<span class="letter">A</span> <span class="letter">B</span> 
</li>

<li>
<span class="letter">D</span> <span class="letter">E</span>
</li>
</ul>
```

CSS:

```
.one {float:left;}
.one a {float:left;position:relative;width:100px;height:60px;display:block;}
.letter {float:left;color:#000;}
.letter:hover {background:#ff0000;}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok.That's it.
http://jsfiddle.net/HECKM/3/

jQuery will get the .ONE href attribute value and apply to LI inside UL.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    var url = $('.one a').attr('href');

    $('ul.test li').click(function(){
        window.location = url;
    });
});
```

Just prepare for your use.

Cya.